# Hiding/Showing post content using AJAX on Wordpress

Tags: ajax, wordpress, post

I was wondering how to go about having post content hidden, and once you click the title having the content slide down via AJAX (hopefully using Wordpress built in AJAX). I was on here yesterday and this community was nice enough to help me make it work with JQuery(thanks again), but I was wondering if it would be possible to have **the hidden content only load when the title is clicked**, instead of having a bunch of hidden content load at once. That way everything would run much smoother.

Here is the JQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {


$(".event-info").hide();
$(".event-title").click(function() {
  var eventInfo = $(this).parent().children(".event-info");
  $('.event-info').not(eventInfo).slideUp();
  eventInfo.slideToggle();
});


});
</script>
```

Html:

```
<div class="event-title">Click on title here to load content</div>

<div class="event-info">content hidden/shown here</div>
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to create a function

try something like this

in your fucntions.php

```
    function PostAjax()
    {
        if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post();
        //Loop content here etc.
        endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query();
    }

    // creating Ajax call for WordPress  
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_PostAjax', 'PostAjax');
    add_action('wp_ajax_PostAjax', 'PostAjax');
```

In your header or footer

```
jQuery(".event-title").click(function(){ 
    jQuery.ajax({  
        type: 'GET',  
        url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php');?>',  
        data: {  
            action: 'PostAjax',
            MyParam: 'MyParamValue'
        },  
        success: function(textStatus){  
           $( '.event-info' ).html( textStatus ); 
        },  
        error: function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){  
            alert(errorThrown);  
        }  
    });  
});
```

});

and your HTML

```
<div class="event-title">Click on title here to load content</div>
<div class="event-info"></div>
```

Comment: Hi Mark! I'll give it a shot! So in the function where you put //Get the post etc. I should plut the worpress get post function? Thanks man youre really helping me out!

Comment: Sorry man i'm not that knowledgable in this stuff yet haha

Comment: @user2457773 i updated my answer with more details